# How can I send performance data from NetApp Harvest to Kafka instead of Graphite server?

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, graphite, netapp

I am using NetApp Harvest to pull performance and usage data from my NetApp storage systems. (https://github.com/szukalski/docker-netapp-harvest). 
NetApp Harvest configuration has a section as follows:
graphite_server   = INSERT_IP_OR_HOSTNAME_OF_GRAPHITE_SERVER_HERE

However, I want to be able to send the data to Kafka first and then from there to InfluxDB (InfluxDB has compatibility for Graphite).

Can someone please guide me as to how can I accomplish this?

A little background on NetApp Harvest: NetApp Harvest is software that connects to a remote host, collects data, calculates and summarizes the data, and posts it to a metrics server. It offers default collection templates for performance information from ONTAP and Data ONTAP 7-mode every 1 minute, and storage capacity information from OnCommand Unified Manager 6+ every 15 minutes. (From their documentation).

I am not sure how to be able to send the data to Kafka? Should I just place the Kafka IP into the graphite_server field?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to me that harvest supports Kafka at all. It seems like it is closed source commercial software, so you probably should create a ticket at your supplier with a feature request.

Comment: thanks. Sure I reached out to them and was told that it is not supported.